# How should I clean this JSON document?

Tags: r, json, data-cleaning

I have created this data set, and it's still really messy.  It is loaded with missing values (each empty day should be empty) and there are two many brackets everywhere.  I want a simple dataframe or other structure (tuple of tuples?) so that there is a Date, a list of currencies, and their numerical exchange rates in each element.

I'm just kinda new at cleaning data in R.

''' {"2018.01.02":{"USD":["1,361.0"],"VND":["5.9983"],"THB":["41.838"],"SEK":["166.31"],"LKR":["8.8732"],"ZAR":["109.96"],"RSD":["13.807"],"SAR":["362.90"],"RUB":["23.589"],"PHP":["27.207"],"PKR":["12.338"],"NOK":["165.88"],"NZD":["966.31"],"NPR":["13.333"],"MYR":["336.30"],"LAK":["16.417"],"KWD":["4,511.3"],"KRW":["127.51"],"KES":["13.198"],"ILS":["392.02"],"IDR":["10.031"],"INR":["21.373"],"HKD":["174.20"],"EGP":["76.591"],"DKK":["219.36"],"CZK":["63.951"],"CNY":["209.17"],"CAD":["1,084.6"],"KHR":["33.750"],"BND":["1,018.7"],"BRL":["410.89"],"BDT":["16.442"],"AUD":["1,062.5"],"JPY":["1,208.8"],"CHF":["1,396.8"],"GBP":["1,839.3"],"SGD":["1,018.0"],"EUR":["1,635.1"]},"2018.01.03":{"USD":["1,359.0"],"VND":["5.9865"],"THB":["41.893"],"SEK":["166.42"],"LKR":["8.8542"],"ZAR":["109.70"],"RSD":["13.791"],"SAR":["362.37"],"RUB":["23.641"],"PHP":["27.232"],"PKR":["12.276"],"NOK":["166.90"],"NZD":["964.38"],"NPR":["13.359"],"MYR":["337.60"],"LAK":["16.397"],"KWD":["4,505.2"],"KRW":["127.67"],"KES":["13.166"],"ILS":["392.41"],"IDR":["10.054"],"INR":["21.415"],"HKD":["173.84"],"EGP":["76.628"],"DKK":["219.85"],"CZK":["64.114"],"CNY":["209.29"],"CAD":["1,086.1"],"KHR":["33.711"],"BND":["1,017.2"],"BRL":["413.46"],"BDT":["16.414"],"AUD":["1,063.4"],"JPY":["1,209.7"],"CHF":["1,398.3"],"GBP":["1,847.6"],"SGD":["1,022.1"],"EUR":["1,639.3"]},"2018.01.04":[],"2018.01.05":{"USD":["1,358.0"],"VND":["5.9792"],"THB":["42.174"],"SEK":["166.60"],"LKR":["8.8371"],"ZAR":["110.20"],"RSD":["13.760"],"SAR":["362.10"],"RUB":["23.790"],"PHP":["27.239"],"PKR":["12.275"],"NOK":["167.90"],"NZD":["971.80"],"NPR":["13.375"],"MYR":["338.95"],"LAK":["16.385"],"KWD":["4,503.7"],"KRW":["127.78"],"KES":["13.137"],"ILS":["393.68"],"IDR":["10.121"],"INR":["21.420"],"HKD":["173.71"],"EGP":["76.707"],"DKK":["219.74"],"CZK":["64.133"],"CNY":["209.14"]'''

There's my JSON file

Comment: Bracket are arrays in json format, so when you were creating the data set, currencies were mapped to arrays that only contain one value(you want to upload them as a primitive value, e.g. double).

Comment: *"each empty day should be empty"*, I think that `"2018.01.04":[]` precisely represents that assertion. Do you disagree? BTW: in R this would neither provide *dates* nor *numeric* values, as `"2018.01.04"` is a string (that, admittedly, can easily be converted to a date), and `"1,208.8"` is again a string (as R does not allow commas as thousands-place holders ... and it's still a string in json-speak). This is quite easily converted, perhaps you should clearly define what you are intending? (Attempted code and desired output are two important components towards communicating those concepts.)

Comment: Thank you both for understanding my question.  I want to:

1) make every value a primitive value
2) simplify the structure so that it can be a dataframe

Comment: It might be helpful to take a look at the [jsonlite::fromJSON](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.6/topics/toJSON%2C%20fromJSON), and one more thing I think your json is missing a couple of closing brackets at the end